# Code that compiles with gcc but not with g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I am writing a program in **c**, but i need to use a **c++** library to work with an ADC's.

In my code I have a library that I wrote called scheduler, this library compiles with no errors with **gcc** but when I try to compile with **g++** I get the error:

```
scheduler.c:55:35: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1
                    tasks[i].func(tasks[i].args);
```

Here is the scheduler struct:

```
typedef struct _tasks_t
{
    char *name;
    unsigned int period; /**< Contains the period the task. If it's 0 it doesn't execute the task */
    void (*func)();      /**< Contains a pointer to the function of the task */
    bool args_on;        /**< true if the function has arguments */
    void *args;          /**< pointer to function args */
} tasks_t;
```

And here are the lines that are generating the error:

```
    /** Goes through every task to check if the time passed is >= to the period and if the period is != 0 */
    for (i = 0; i < tasks_size; i++)
    {

        if ((time_ms - t_last[i] >= tasks[i].period) && (tasks[i].period != 0))
        {
            t_last[i] = time_ms; /** Saves the "new" last time that the task was executed */
            if (tasks[i].args_on)
            { /** Executes the task function */
                tasks[i].func(tasks[i].args);
            }
            else
            {
                tasks[i].func();
            }
        }
    }
```

[EDIT]: I solved the problem by writing `void (*func)(void *)` and now I pass function arguments in the for of an array or a struct.

Answer (score 5):

`void (*func)()` is a function pointer to a function with *unspecified* arguments, when interpreted as C, but a function pointer to a function with *0* arguments, when interpreted as C++ (equivalent to `void (*func)(void)` in C).

`tasks[i].func(tasks[i].args);` calls it with one argument, which is invalid in C++.

Comment: How do I make `void (*func)()` to be a pointer to a function with unspecified arguments?

Comment: `void (*func)(...)` MAY work (in C++ only), but it would be better to specify the expected arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, just one question. 
The type of arguments change from task to task. Imagine I have: task_1 (int a) , task2(char b). How could I specify the expected arguments?

Comment: Maybe with something like `std::function`?

Comment: @DiogoFerreira If the functions expect arguments of different types, then your C code already has undefined behavior. You are trying to pass all of them a `void*`.